# Django Nested inline formset-- nested form does not save to DB, no errors thrown

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

We have a few nested inline formsets in an application. Ideally, the goal is to allow for dynamic and unlimited population of these fields so that users can add an arbitrary number of notes.  The form renders, the JS calls are populating; however, I am not seeing the update on the nested from manager.

This is my first Django project and I am not finding anything regarding what is causing the hang up.  The Organization is saved in the DB, but the notes are not.

Thanks in advance for any help

Model.py:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    //irrelevant organization information//
class OrganizationNote(AbstractNotes):
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
```

modelforms.py:

```
class OrganizationForm(AbstractBigThree):
class Meta:
    model = custModels.Organization
    fields = '__all__'
orgNoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(custModels.Organization, custModels.OrganizationNote, 
form=OrganizationForm, extra=0)
```

ModelView.py

```
class OrganizationCreateView(CreateView, AbstractOrganizationView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    org_note_form = orgNoteFormSet()
    
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              org_note_form=org_note_form))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(OrganizationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        data['notes'] = orgNoteFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        data['notes'] = orgNoteFormSet()
    return data

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    notes = context['notes']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()
        if notes.is_valid():
            notes.instance = self.object
            notes.save()
    return super(OrganizationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return '/portal'
```

template:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
    {% block __file__ %}
    <!-- filename == organization_create_form.html -->
    {% endblock %}
    {% block container %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".inline.{{ org_note_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ org_note_form.prefix }}",
    })
    })
    </script>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="thermometer">
        <div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="back-link">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
            &gt;&gt;<a class="back-link" style="padding-left:10px;"href="">Organization List</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 main">
        <h1>Create Organization</h1>
        {% if form.errors %}
         {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
            <div id = "form_set">
                <legend>Notes</legend>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Add Note" id="add_more">

            <div id="form_set">
                {{ org_note_form.management_form }}
                {{ org_note_form.non_form_errors}}
                {% for form in org_note_form.forms %}
                    {{form.non_field_errors}}
                    {{form.errors}}
                    <table class='no_error'>
                        {{ form }}
                    </table>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
                <table class='no_error'>
                    <fieldset>
                        {{ org_note_form.empty_form}}
                        <div class="inline {{ org_note_form.prefix }}">
                            {{ form.note.errors }}
                            {{ form.note.label_tag }}
                            {{ form.note }}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input style="margin-top: 30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> $('#add_more').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_organizationnote_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_organizationnote_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});</script>
```

the issue was solved by editing the prefix of the model manager.  By default django names the prefix as table_set which was missing from above.

Comment: add `related_name='your_field_name'` to remove `_set` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

add another option to your code:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
  print(form.errors)
  ...
```

to see if you have any validation errors in your form, don't forget to check errors in your inline

Comment: There were no errors present. The prefix isn't updating the actual inlineformset prefix so each record has its own management form.  I have pivoted to using django-dynamic-formsets, but even that isn't bolting in as described.  I can post additional information in a few minutes.